# Force a .txt file to download after creating list of mysql result

Tags: php, mysql

I want to download a file which includes the results of my mysql query but my problem is, the .txt file includes only the last result of my mysql query. It should includes actually 5 results like this:

http://user:password@server.com:8080

Can someone show me where here the problem is?

```
<?php
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT serverurl FROM ibn");
    echo mysql_error();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT streamport,streamname FROM streams");
    echo mysql_error();
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { 

    $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT client_username,client_openpasswd FROM clients WHERE `client_id` = '$id' ");
    echo mysql_error();
    while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) { 

    $streamurl= $row['serverurl'];
    $streamport = $row2['streamport'];
    $streamuser= $row3['client_username'];
    $streampassword= $row3['client_openpasswd'];
    $streamchannel= $row2['streamname'];

    echo "<p>http://$streamuser:$streampassword@$streamurl:$streamport</p>";
                }   
            }

    }

//Generate text file on the fly

header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=bouquet.txt");

?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: you shouldn't be querying the database in the loop like this, particularly if the query is the same on each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic output can be achieved by moving your calls to `header()` to the top of the script and emitting your data later. The header commands will only be effective if they're issued before any output is sent to the client.

You can demonstrate this with a simple script:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=bouquet.txt");
echo "A line of text\n";
```

The remainder of your code is more problematic. It's not clear why you're doing this, but the effect of your code is to produce the cartesian product of the three tables. i.e. every row in every table is combined with every row in every other table. I doubt this is actually what you want, but...

You can achieve the same result more efficiently by using an SQL `JOIN` with no `ON` clause. Using that and concatenating the required fields you can do almost everything you want in a single SQL query:

```
select
  concat('http://',
      clientname,':',
      clientopenpassword,'@',
      serverurl,':',
      streamsport)
  as URL 
from ibn, streams, clients where client_id=1
```

I'll leave converting this to a working PHP script as an exercise for the reader, but your code above provides a good template. Remember, only one query and one loop to fetch the result and emit it.

Note that `mysql_*()` is deprecated - use `mysqli_*()` for new code. You should also watch for possible SQL injection where you use `$id` in your query.